# Implicit vs. unnamed packages

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

About [packages](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#packages) in XSLT 3.0, are implicit and unnamed packages the same thing? Assuming that neither one can be used by other packages, why does it say:

> For compatibility reasons, all the named templates and modes declared
>   in the package are made public.

Comment: Your quote from the specification does not mention implicit or unnamed packages. Perhaps you could include more context here? Is your question what the "compatibility reasons" are? Or if , say, named templates without a `visibility` attribute inside an explicit `xsl:package` without a `name` attribute are also made public?

Comment: @MathiasMüller why are named templates and modes made public, if they cannot be referenced since the package has no name?

Comment: It might have to do with pre-3.0 XSLT (hence "compatibility") where e.g. named templates can be imported into other stylesheets. Since any stylesheet is now converted to an implicit package, not declaring them public might break existing code. (This is just a guess, I have no idea if visibility has an influence on imports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implicit package is one rooted at an `xsl:stylesheet` rather than `xsl:package` element; an implicit package will always be unnamed. But you can also have a package rooted at an `xsl:package` element with no `@name` attribute; this is unnamed but not implicit.

Making the components public means that they are visible to a calling API, for example any named template can be used as an entry point specifying `call-template` and a named template. If they were private, which would otherwise be the default, they could not be referenced externally in this way.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Can you change the declared visibility of a component in an implicit package, or do I have to change the root element to `xsl:package`?

Comment: I think you can do pretty well everything with an implicit package other than using it as the target of an `xsl:use-package`.